# PHPBB Table Doesn't Exist Error - After a potential upgrade or extension addition

Tags: php, upgrade, phpbb, phpbb3

Some of my site admins attempted an upgrade or extension addition, and the following has now happened.

```
SQL ERROR [ mysql4 ]

Table '***.phpbb3_ext' doesn't exist [1146]
```

That table doesn't exist, as I already tried looking for it. I also tried searching every file and even the db dump (grep), to see if it's referenced anywhere. I'm assuming it's built dynamically.

I'm looking for any PHPBB pros out there. Is there a specific trigger that has been activated, where it's in an upgrade mode? How can I turn that off, and stop it from looking for that table.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you haven't run the database updater necessary to complete the upgrade from phpBB 3.0 to phpBB 3.1. All the necessary steps can be found here: https://www.phpbb.com/support/docs/en/3.1/ug/upgradeguide/upgrade3/ (see point 5)

Comment: This fixed our installation after the upgrade failed.

Comment: The linked solution fails to fix the problem.

Comment: @MartinSpamer any more details why not?